# passing the result of a boolean expression to a twig function

Tags: php, twig, expression, timber

I have a custom function that's being added to the Twig object like so:

```
...
    add_filter('get_twig', array(get_class(),'add_twig_functions'));
...

public static function add_twig_functions($twig)
{
    $twig->addFunction(new Twig_SimpleFunction('get_table', array(get_class(), 'get_table')));

    return $twig;
}

...

public static function get_table($cycle, $visible = true, $id = null)
{
    ....
}
```

Inside a twig template, I am trying to call it like so:

```
{{ get_table('mth', user_data.cycle = 'Monthly', 'table-mth') }}
```

However I'm getting an error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Twig_Error_Syntax' with message
>   'A parameter name must be a string, "Twig_Node_Expression_GetAttr"
>   given

My intended result is that the `$visible` parameter is passed as true if the `user_data.cycle` context variable is equal to 'Monthly', but clearly I'm not doing it correctly.

I also tried changing my call to:

```
{{ get_table('mth', (user_data.cycle = 'Monthly'), 'table-mth') }}
```

However this just gives me:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Twig_Error_Syntax' with message
>   'An opened parenthesis is not properly closed. Unexpected token
>   "operator" of value "=" ("punctuation" expected with value ")")

Is there an expected way to pass a boolean expression to a twig function? Timber is at version 1.1.6, for what it's worth. All the documentation I've been able to find so far on extending with functions is at http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/advanced.html, but it doesn't really cover parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Well this is just me misremembering how comparisons work in twig... I had the impression that `=` in Twig was the equivalent of PHP's `==`, and `==` in twig was the equivalent of PHP's `===`, but I don't know where I got that impression because it's wrong.

```
{{ get_table('mth', (user_data.cycle == 'Monthly'), 'table-mth') }}
```

works fine and as expected. There goes a pointless hour of troubleshooting.